# how to insert multiple variable in databse table through sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I want insert multiple variable as `VALUES` in my database table. here is my code

```
include 'database_connect.php';

$namef=  $_post["fnam"];
$lnamel= $_post["lnam"];
$addres= $_post["addres"];
$mail= $_post["email"];
$countr= $_post["countr"];
$db= $_post["do"];
$m= $_post["m"];
$pasword= $_post["pas"];

$insertSql= "INSERT INTO abcd(Id, First_name, Last_name, Address, Email, Country, Date_of_birth, Mobile_number, Password, Status) 
VALUES(NULL,'$namef', '$namel', '$addres', '$mail', '$countr', '$db', '$m', '$pasword', '0')";

if(mysql_query($insertSql))
    header("location: login_success.php");
else
    header("location: wrong_inf.php");
```

here only in Id and status field are inserted and all other fields are going empty even though i am giving some input in those inputs.

I don't know how to solve this.

Note:here `Id` is `integer` type and `status` is `tinyint` type and all other field is `varchar` type.

Comment: try print_r($_POST) , what it says ?

Comment: try changing `$_post[""]` to `$_POST[''] `

Comment: It seems odd that you are setting your ID to NULL. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Please make sure to carefully read and understand this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 It will help prevent your DB from being hacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Variables are case-sensitives

try

```
$namef=$_POST["fnam"];
$lnamel=$_POST["lnam"];
```

ETC....

Answer (score 2):

For using post variable you need use

```
$_POST['fieldname']
```

and not as

```
$_post["fieldname"]
```

Because the `$_POST` array is case sensitive in php

Also always check whether query is executed correctly or not using `mysql_error()` and the proceed

```
$query = mysql_query($insertSql) or die(mysql_error());

if($query)
  {
   // updated
  }
else
   {
    // not updated
   }
```

And at last i advice you not use `mysql_*` functions  and start use `mysqli_*` function or `PDO`

Answer (score 1):

write `$_REQUEST` OR `$_POST` instead of `$_post`

also use exit after calling `header("..");`  and escape before sql execution to prevent injections

your modified code is

```
include 'database_connect.php';

$namef=  $_REQUEST["fnam"];
$lnamel= $_REQUEST["lnam"];
$addres= $_REQUEST["addres"];
$mail= $_REQUEST["email"];
$countr= $_REQUEST["countr"];
$db= $_REQUEST["do"];
$m= $_REQUEST["m"];
$pasword= $_REQUEST["pas"];

$namef = mysql_real_escape_string($namef);
$lnamel = mysql_real_escape_string($lnamel);
$addres = mysql_real_escape_string($addres);
$mail= mysql_real_escape_string($mail);
$countr = mysql_real_escape_string($countr);
$db = mysql_real_escape_string($db);
$m = mysql_real_escape_string($m);
$pasword = mysql_real_escape_string($pasword);

$insertSql= "INSERT INTO abcd(Id, First_name, Last_name, Address, Email, Country, Date_of_birth, Mobile_number, Password, Status) 
VALUES(NULL,'$namef', '$namel', '$addres', '$mail', '$countr', '$db', '$m', '$pasword', '0')";

if(mysql_query($insertSql))
{
    header("location: login_success.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
    header("location: wrong_inf.php");
    exit;
}
```

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` is deprecated now user `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

You could start by writing out your SQL string after you build it to see if the values are being added properly:

```
echo $insertSql;
```

If there are blank items in there, check your `$_POST` data are being passed through properly:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

(And as krishna pointed out, you're using lowercase $_post when you should be using uppercase $_POST.)

Also, though you didn't ask about it, you shouldn't write data directly from the `$_POST` array to your database without sanitizing it first. Best bet is to use PDO, but if you're going to use the `mysql_*` functions, then use `mysql_real_escape_string` on each item you are writing to the database, like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES ("' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item']) . '")';
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the error is undefine variable is `$namel`   in sql

replaece it with  `$lnamel`